# How to Delete a blob from Azure blob v12 SDK for Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

How can I delete Azure Blob through Node.js and I am using Azure library v12 SDK for Node.js (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs)

I could not find delete blob method, I want to delete blob by name.

Comment: Check this delete metjod.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobclient?view=azure-node-latest#delete-blobdeleteoptions-

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just as @Georage said in the comment, you can use the `delete` method to delete a blob.

Here is my demo:

```
const { BlobServiceClient,ContainerClient, StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

// Load the .env file if it exists
require("dotenv").config();

async function streamToString(readableStream) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const chunks = [];
      readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
        chunks.push(data.toString());
      });
      readableStream.on("end", () => {
        resolve(chunks.join(""));
      });
      readableStream.on("error", reject);
    });
  }

async function main() {
    const AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING;
    const blobServiceClient = await BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);
    const containerClient = await blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("test");
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient("test.txt")
    const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
    console.log(await streamToString(downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody));
    const blobDeleteResponse = blockBlobClient.delete();
    console.log((await blobDeleteResponse).clientRequestId);
}

main().catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error running sample:", err.message);
  });
```

After running this sample, the `test.txt` file was removed from the `test` container.

Answer (score 12):

While Jack's answer works, it is more complicated than it needs to be. Instead of creating the `blockBlobClient` and then deleting it, a simpler way would be to use:

`containerClient.deleteBlob('blob-name')`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as client.delete('...') only marks the blob for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

**`@JackJia`'s answer is perfectly works!**

---

This is my code with `ES6 JavaScript : Typescript :)`

> I created this as a seperate function. So that I can only pass the blob name to it.

```
import { BlobServiceClient } from "@azure/storage-blob";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const azureBlobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(
  process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING!
);
const containerClient = azureBlobServiceClient.getContainerClient(
  process.env.BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME!
);

export const deleteBlob = async (blobName: string) => {
  const blobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
  await blobClient.delete();
};
```

---

Pass the `blobName` to the function & It will handle all the other things :)

> FYI: make sure to pass a `String` type to `blobName`. Otherwise typescript will gonna cry :(